# How to prevent component re-render (update) inside animations with REACT

Tags: reactjs, transition, react-transition-group, react-spring, react-animations

These past few days, i've been playing around with different animation libraries for React, in an effort to find a solution for transitioning between views (not routes), where a view would be a component wrapping other components and so on.

so far i tried:
`react-transtition-group`
`react-animations`
`react-spring`

Still need to experiment with `react-motion`'s Transition...

...and there are a lot more out there, but all these, do what i need, except for one thing... while each state of the transition/style is applied, the child component(s) always update, triggering a re-render (which makes sense by the way), unless the child's `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false, or is wrapped inside a PureComponent, both of which are not a solution, since you might (surely) want to do "things" with your component after the transition ends.

All the examples out there, serve their purpose, but they all use either functional components, or simple strings, for demo purposes, none of which one should care if are re-rendered or not, but a simple modification that would log every time the component is rendered, will show that they render multiple times during the transition.

Oddly enough, nobody seems to care, or is unaware. I have found very few questions or issues regarding this matter, though it's very much real, and the libs are very poorly documented on this.

Please share your solutions for avoiding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is to wrap the transitioned children/views inside a simple PureComponent, to prevent them from re-rendering, still it doesn't seem right.

Comment: Please add this additional info to your question. Not as an answer.

Comment: An example would be useful